# Magento 1 - MTF How to run functional test ?

Tags: magento-1.9, unit-tests, phpunit, tests

Magento 1 ships with a */tests/* folder containing functional test based on PHPUnit and Selenium
( note: you shouldn't deploy this folder to live site :)

I'm looking for some information in order to run those tests and implement my own.

Comment: Do you know how to run test without selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

M1 (from 1.9) and M2 have the same way of test running.
In M1.9 you have it out of box.

So just read the manual "how to"
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/mtf/mtf_quickstart/mtf_quickstart_runtest.html

Hope it helps

Comment: I was able to setup MTF using the guide you shared ( the guide is for M2 but works fine also on M1 ) and run some functional test with selenium... Do you have any idea if there are some unit test available on M1 ?

Comment: Out of box - not. But an example you can find in third-party extension.  For example: https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_TemplateHints/tree/master/app/code/community/Aoe/TemplateHints/Test/Model